# PHP form validation not showing the error

Tags: php, html, forms

HTML Form

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label style="padding-top: 10px;" class="col-form-label">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your name" name="name" id="name">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            <span><?php echo $nameErr ?></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-form-label">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your email here" name="email" id="email">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            <span><?php echo $mailErr ?></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-form-label">Phone Number</label>
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your phone number here" name="phone" id="phone">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-form-label">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Type a password here" name="pass" id="pass">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            <span><?php echo $passErr ?></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-form-label">Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Retype the password here" name="cpass" id="cpass">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            <span aria-hidden="true"><?php echo $cpassErr ?></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row offset-sm-9" style="padding-left: 10px;">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" name="btn" value="signup">Register</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP code

```
$nameErr = $mailErr = $passErr = $cpassErr = "";

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    if(empty($_POST['name'])){
        $nameErr = "Name is required !";
    }elseif (empty($_POST['email'])) {
         $mailErr = "Email is required !";
    }elseif (empty($_POST['pass']) || ($_POST['pass'] < 6)) {
         $passErr = "Password is required !";
         $passErr = "At least 6 characters required !";
    }elseif (empty($_POST['cpass']) || ($_POST['pass']) != ($_POST['cpass'])) {
         $cpassErr = "Confirm password is required !";
         $cpassErr = "Confirmation password do not match !";
    }
}
```

I am trying to validate the form with php. The errors will be shown in a div with bootstap alert class. The problem is even before click the submit button there's errors saying undefined variables in that divs. And when user click the submit button nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `isset()`

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <span><?php if(isset($nameErr) { echo $nameErr; } ?></span>
</div>
```

And you can remove some of your php code.

```
//$nameErr = $mailErr = $passErr = $cpassErr = ""; << Remove it

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    if(empty($_POST['name'])){
        $nameErr = "Name is required !";
    }elseif (empty($_POST['email'])) {
         $mailErr = "Email is required !";
    }elseif (empty($_POST['pass']) || ($_POST['pass'] < 6)) {
         $passErr = "Password is required !";
         $passErr = "At least 6 characters required !";
    }elseif (empty($_POST['cpass']) || ($_POST['pass']) != ($_POST['cpass'])) {
         $cpassErr = "Confirm password is required !";
         $cpassErr = "Confirmation password do not match !";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because, at first time the error variables are not availabl, and you are trying to access them. So, try this:

```
<?php echo (isset($cpassErr) ? $cpassErr : ''); ?>
```

**isset()** is use to check if a variable is available or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the validation errors like this

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label">Confirm Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Retype the password here" name="cpass" id="cpass">
    <?php if(isset($cpassErr)): ?>
       <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
          <span aria-hidden="true"><?php echo $cpassErr ?></span>
       </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Or do something similar to the previous answer, but this will work if you have set a background for example. You could also do something similar to

```
class='<?= isset($cpassErr) ? 'alert' : ''; ?>'
```

if you didn't want to wrap them in ifs etc.